# Parsing data in the format 20120101 1:00

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the given time and date information to the UTC equivalent. My code is:

```
from datetime import datetime      

Time = [int (i) for i in Time]
datetime_Time= datetime.strptime ('20120101 1:00','%Y%m%d %I:M')
```

The error I am receiving is

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20120101 1:00'

Comment: You just forgot the `%` in front of `M`

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that your assigned dateTimeFormat is invalid.
You can try this format :

```
import datetime
dateTimeFormat = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:S"
customTime = "20120101 1:00"
processedTime = datetime.strptime(customTime,dateTimeFormat)
print processedTime

2012-01-01 01:10:00
```

Comment: I have tried your code but I am receiving the following error message "AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'"

Comment: It should be  `datetime.datetime.strptime(customTime, dateTimeFormat)` as you are importing `datetime`, not `datetime.datetime`.